# Solidity inline assembly not compiling

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have the following code snippet for checking a transfer was successful. This function is taken from an already live project, though that project is using `pragam 4.2.0`. I am using `pragma 6.12.0`, so I am assuming that it is some kind of versioning issue with Yul but I am struggling to find the correct information.

The code:

```js
    function checkSuccess(
    )
        private
        pure
        returns (bool)
    {
        uint256 returnValue = 0;

        assembly {
            // check number of bytes returned from last function call
            switch returndatasize

            // no bytes returned: assume success
            case 0x0 {
                returnValue := 1
            }

            // 32 bytes returned: check if non-zero
            case 0x20 {
                // copy 32 bytes into scratch space
                returndatacopy(0x0, 0x0, 0x20)

                // load those bytes into returnValue
                returnValue := mload(0x0)
            }

            // not sure what was returned: don't mark as success
            default { }
        }

        return returnValue != 0;

    }
```

I get the following error when compiling:

```js
ParserError: Expected '(' but got reserved keyword 'case'
            case 0x0 {
            ^--^
```

Anyone with more expertise with inline assembly who could shed some light on this is a +1 from me!

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `()` to the opcode `returndatasize`. For `0.6.12`, check the [EVM Dialect](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.12/yul.html#evm-dialect) to see inline assembly instruction syntax.

Change this line:

`switch returndatasize`

Into:

`switch returndatasize()`